# Is there a paper/implementation/tool on automatically finding/suggesting similar questions for a given question?

Tags: reference-request, natural-language-processing

I would like to know whether there is a method to find similar questions for a given question, just like this stackexchange.com does.

Is there any paper or tools?
I tried keywords such as "deduplication" and "linking" but it was not successful.

Comment: I think you'll need to tell us more.  Similar questions, from among what corpus?  (a similar question on this same site, or a similar question somewhere on the Internet?)  What techniques in NLP are you familiar with and what research have you done?  Are you familiar with how search engines work?  Are you familiar with techniques like TF-IDF, latent semantic analysis, and latent semantic indexing?  Have you tried to find a book on information retrieval?  There are lots of resources on these topics online.

Comment: This is a question in the field of "information retrieval" and if your data is unstructured, like a simple string-question, you have to use similarity algorithms (maybe based on synonyms and other real-language stuff). If your data has more structure, like the tags here on stackexchange, you can use that information and improve your similarity-algorithms.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I am familiar with NLP and IR techniques. Rather than the direction I should do for question deduplication, I would like to know whether there is any paper, or known tools so that I can compare in research.